# OpenId Access Token updating values client side

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have a claim AllowEmailNotifications which allows the user to toggle notifications on and off in their profile client side. I originally had this value in their user profile object which is stored in sessionStorage client side which is updated in the database as well as sessionStorage when they toggle this value.

Is it safe to move this value to the Access Token and update the access token client side which is also stored in Session Storage or is this considered tampering with the token? I need it server side or should I just make a call to the database to get this value in the web service?

I'm not sure what is considered best practices with updating values in the access token via the app instead of the Authorization Provider?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to "update" an access token client-side, only replace it with a new one via a refresh using the refresh token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An access token should definitely not be updated at client side.
Your client would need the signing key, because otherwise the signature of the token would be wrong and it wouldn't be accepted anymore.

I would just keep the setting in the database and get it from there when needed.

Comment: I was even thinking about the singing key, forgot all about that. Thank you.